# Bootcamp uses half of my Ram

Tags: windows-7, memory, boot-camp

I have a Macbook Pro with 4G Ram DDR3
I installed Windows 7 32 bits on my bootcamp partition.

I believe that Bootcamp would use all my hardware and in the DxDiag

In the Windows Task manager, however, it says a total 2229MB of memory and in Nvidia Geforce Experience 2.18GB of RAM.

So I am confused, am I using 2GB or 4GB of ram? If I am using 2GB, how can I allocate the remaining 2GB ??

**Below is my DxDiag**

System Information

- Time of this report: 9/5/2013, 15:53:13
- Language: English (Regional Setting: English) System Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
- System Model: MacBookPro6,2
- BIOS: Default System BIOS
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU       M 620  @ 2.67GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.7GHz
- Memory: 4096MB RAM
- Available OS Memory: 2230MB RAM
- Page File: 1988MB used, 2469MB available
- Windows Dir: C:\Windows
- DirectX Version: DirectX 11 DX Setup Parameters: Not found    User DPI Setting: Using System DPI  System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100
  percent)
- DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
- DxDiag Version: 6.01.7601.17514 32bit Unicode

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your graphic card uses shared memory.  Besides that fact a 32-bit Windows operating system cannot use 100% of 4096MB of memory.  The most you would get is around 3.25-3.5GB depending on your hardware IRQ requirements.

Comment: why don't you install the 64Bit Windows 7?

Comment: Well now that Ramhoun explained that 32Bit limits the ram, the idea is to install 64Bit windows. Thank you so much for the explanation!